# passing input from keyboard to a python3 application in centos

Tags: linux, python-3.x, bash, keyboard, centos

I am trying to take an input from keyboard to a python3 program. See code below:

```
keyInput = input('Would you like to see another plot? y/n: ')
print(keyInput)
if keyInput == 'y':
    continue
elif keyInput == 'n':
    break
else:
    print('Command ' + keyInput+' is not valid')
```

I keeps on getting an error like this :bash: y: command not found...

I am developing the code on centos7. I think the shell is trying to process the command first, and not passing the input into my program.

How do I bypass the linux shell? or any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: The code seems incomplete. I assume the enclosing loop somehow got lost during copy-pasting? Also, please check that the code is indented properly. To make it appear in a code block, it has to be indented by additional four spaces. There is a `{}` button for that in the text editor gui.

Comment: How are you running your script? Try running it like `python script.py`. Or set a shebang and then you can run it with `./script.py`.